# Moving Data between Worksheets based on a key

Tags: vba, excel

In both worksheets I have a key in column A. Not all of the key values are in both worksheets.
For each key value in column A of Worksheet 1, I want to find the corresponding key in worksheet 2 and move the data in column B of worksheet 2 into column B of worksheet 1.

I have never programmed a macro so I am completely lost for writing this code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for VBA here, Philip.

Try this formula in cell B1 of Sheet1:

```
=IFERROR(vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,false),"")
```

If you are on XL 2003, then do this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,false)),"",vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,false))
```

Then drag this formula down for the rest of your data in Column A of Sheet1.

*NB - Sheet2 is the assumed name of your Worksheet2, you may need to change to fit your needs.*

*NB2 - you can lookup `vlookup` in Excel Help (or online) to better understand what it does*

Comment: Excellent! I was unaware of the vlookup function. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1895749 -> great! please mark the answer as complete if you fill it satisfied your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to use a macro for this?  It sounds to me like you are using Excel and a simple VLOOKUP formula would do what you need.

A VLOOKUP looks like this: =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)

Where A1 is your reference cell (in this case you "key" in column A).

Sheet2!$A:$B is the lookup table (in this case columns A and B from the second sheet).

2 is the column number that you want data from, counting from the left (in this case the second column, column B)

FALSE tells the formula to only return values for exact matches.  TRUE returns the closest match in the lookup table.